# Gif creation with Imagemagick - convert : Images are overlapping

Tags: imagemagick, animated-gif

I am trying to make a gif with images using convert. But in the resulting gif, the images are just stacking one over the other. 
Here is the created gif  : https://i.imgur.com/EgISW2y.gif

I tried creating it with simple command :

`$ convert -delay 8 -loop 0 plot_* result.gif`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the `-dispose` setting with `previous` option, which disposes the previous frames after they are displayed:

```
convert -dispose previous -delay 8 plot_* -loop 0 result.gif
```

Further reading [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/#dispose).

Comment: @hadik Glad I could help.

Comment: thanks a lot!  little late, but please accept my appreciation! :D